# How to show submenu on hover and keep it that way

Tags: html, jquery, hover, dropdown, submenu

I've made a little menu and try to find a working code to show the submenu on hover. All I managed to get is that it shows on hovering, but it doesn't stay when you hover over the sub items.
Ive tried using jQuery onmouseover but it doesn't hold on hovering the links.

```css
header .container .links ul li.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

header .container .links ul li.dropdown ul {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 39px 0 0 0;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  min-width: 240px;
  z-index: 500;
}

header .container .links ul li.dropdown ul li {
  padding: 17px 20px;
}

header .container .links ul li.dropdown ul li a {
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #222;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header .container .links ul li.dropdown ul li:hover a {
  color: #82945c;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="">Link 2</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="">Link 2A</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 2B</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="">Link 3A</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link 3B</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try out this basic structure to build the dropdown to automatically close:

```
        .dropdown-menu ul {
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        .dropdown li {
            display: none;
        }
```

```
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Link 2</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="">Link 2A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 2B</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Link 3</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="">Link 3A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 3B</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>`
```

If you want to keep the dropdown open I suggest you using jQuery to change the css:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".dropdown-menu li").mouseover(function () {
                $(this).find('ul').children().css('display', 'block');
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve above using HTML & CSS only.
Initially hide all submenu and show on hover by adding  two css rule like below:

```css
 
 header .container .links ul li.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

header .container .links ul li.dropdown ul {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 39px 0 0 0;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  min-width: 240px;
  z-index: 500;

}
 
header .container .links ul li.dropdown ul li {
  padding: 17px 20px;
}

header .container .links ul li.dropdown ul li a {
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #222;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header .container .links ul li.dropdown ul li:hover a {
  color: #82945c;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.submenu {
  display: none;
}
li.dropdown:hover ul.submenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="">Link 2</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="">Link 2A</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 2B</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="">Link 3A</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Link 3B</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```